# SUM aggregation do not work on empty subqueries with DRUID

Tags: sql, count, case, distinct, druid

Assuming I am executing the following two queries on Druid:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT field_1) FROM my_table WHERE field_2 = 10 
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT field_1) FROM my_table WHERE field_2 = 11
```

I tried to combine both counts in one single query with a sum aggregation like the following:

```
Select q1.totalcount + q2.totalcount FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT field_1) AS totalcount 
FROM my_table WHERE field_2 = 10) as q1,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT field_1) AS totalcount 
FROM my_table WHERE field_2 = 11) as q2
```

And it works well UNLESS one of the two counts returns 0 rows.

In that case I receive a `Query returned no data` message and I don't have any final result from the SUM query even if one of the two subqueries returned some results.

How can I solve this?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. Skip those redundant parentheses to avoid confusion - i.e. simply do `COUNT(DISTINCT field_1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation with `CASE` expressions:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN field_2 = 10 THEN field_1 END) +
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN field_2 = 11 THEN field_1 END)
FROM my_table 
WHERE field_2 IN (10, 11);
```

Note that, in case there is a `field_1` value that is common in both groups of `field_2 = 10` and `field_2 = 11`, it will be counted in both groups, just like your code.

Answer (score 1):

why not counting everything together?:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(field_1)) FROM my_table WHERE field_2 in (10,11)
```

also the way you are adding up counts , if there any common field_1 between two count selects , you will count them twice.

Comment: That's a good solution but works only for additions. I'm looking for a more general solution that allows me to do subtractions, divisions and multiplications.